# Is it possible to send HTAREPLY with javascript without window.close()

Tags: javascript, batch-file, hta

I am building an HTA/Batch script that includes an interface for a user to send an htareply to the batch script that will send a link to a server to execute a build script on Jenkins.  Everything works great but I was wondering if I can leave the hta window open so the user can select another option if required. Any ideas?

I attempted to remove the `window.close()` from the javascript but then it does not send the htareply to the batch script.

```
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off
setlocal

echo Select an option:
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0"') do set "HTAreply=%%a"
echo End of HTA window, reply: "%HTAreply%"
PAUSE
goto :EOF

-->


<HTML>
<HEAD>
<HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="no" SYSMENU="no" >

<TITLE>HTA Radio Buttons</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
window.resizeTo(440,170);

var reply = "No button selected";
function sendreply(){
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  fso.GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(reply);
  //window.close();
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<p>Select an option.</p>
<label><input type="radio" name="option1" onclick="reply=this.value" 
value="option1">Option1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option2" onclick="reply=this.value" 
value="option2">Option2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option3" onclick="reply=this.value" 
value="option3">Option3</label>
<br><br>
<button onclick="sendreply()">Submit</button>
<button onclick="window.close()">Close</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

What I would like to happen is if the user selects and option and submits, the hta window remains open until they select "close".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for /F` command works this way: *first* execute the nested command, collect all its output and wait for it to terminate; *then* start to execute the commands in the `for` body with the collected lines. For this reason, you can *not* use `for /F` if you want simultaneous (parallel) execution...

You may use a pipe with the HTA part in the left side and Batch part in the right side. However, when `set /P` command read input from a pipe, it presents a strange behavior...

The solution is to use an auxiliary file, so HTA part write to it and Batch part read from it:

```
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off
setlocal

rem Initialize Batch side interface the first time
if "%~1" equ "interface" goto :interface

rem Empty pipe file
cd . > pipeFile.txt

echo Select an option:

rem Start HTA-Batch interface
mshta.exe "%~F0" >> pipeFile.txt  |  "%~F0" interface < pipeFile.txt
PAUSE
del pipeFile.txt
goto :EOF


:interface

set "HTAreply="
set /P "HTAreply="
if "%HTAreply%" equ "" goto interface

echo Reply: "%HTAreply%"
if "%HTAreply%" neq "EOF" goto interface
echo End of HTA window

goto :EOF

-->


<HTML>
<HEAD>
<HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="no" SYSMENU="no" >

<TITLE>HTA Radio Buttons</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
window.resizeTo(440,170);

var reply = "No button selected";
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
function sendreply(){
  fso.GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(reply);
  //window.close();
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<p>Select an option.</p>
<label><input type="radio" name="option1" onclick="reply=this.value" 
value="option1">Option1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option2" onclick="reply=this.value" 
value="option2">Option2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option3" onclick="reply=this.value" 
value="option3">Option3</label>
<br><br>
<button onclick="sendreply()">Submit</button>
<button onclick="fso.GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine('EOF'); window.close()">Close</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

In this solution HTA and Batch parts are started via a pipeline `|` just to run both in parallel; remember that the communication between the two parts is performed via the pipeFile...

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I also appreciate you going into additional detail.